# conference address undefined control sequence in conference class

Tags: addresses

I have tried to use command \address{} to add the address that is corresponding to the specific author. However, it alerts the error of "\address is a undefined control sequence" in \documentclass{conference}.

so, how can I add authors as follows:
[image]

not as follows:

[image]

And following is the code. where the college may be long and it would cross two rows.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}


\title{xx}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{author1, author2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{This is the college and may be very long.  \\
This is the University\\
 Email:xx@xx.org} \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author1, author2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{This is the college and may be very long.  \\
This is the University\\
 Email:xx@xx.org} \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author1, author2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{This is the college and may be very long.  \\
This is the University\\
 Email:xx@xx.org}
}

%\address{} % where alerts undefined control sequence.


\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Anyone can help Me? Thanks !

Comment: Welcome, it is importnt to show us a compilable example. There is too much unknown right now, to exactly reproduce the issue.

Comment: use `ieeeconf` class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is very easy one, just replace the \author with the following:

```
\author{author1$^{*}$,
        author2$^{*}$,
        author3$^{**}$,
        author4$^{***}$\\
$^{*}$College of xx, xx University.\\
$^{**}$College of xx, xx univserity.\\
$^{***}$xx, xx University and may be very long.\\
Email: \emph{\{xx, xx\}@xx.org}, \emph{xx@xx.edu.cn}, \emph{xx@xx.edu.au  }     
}
```